# How to reduce Spacing in an iterated row in Flutter Application

Tags: flutter

In my Flutter project I am trying to reduce unecessary spacing after the rows
I have the following UI in a flutter project

```
  for (final stuff in stuffs)
    if (stuff.item == item.id)
    Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          const Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text('Order: '),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(stuff.order.toString()),
            ),
          ),
          const Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: Text('Reps: '),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 1,
            child: ListTile(
              title: Text(stuff.repetitions.toString()),
            ),
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: const Icon(Icons.edit),
            onPressed: () async {},
          ),
          IconButton(
            icon: Icon(Icons.delete),
            onPressed: () async {},
          ),
        ],
    ),
```

This is the current outcome:
[image]

My question and objective is how to reduce the spacing between each iteration. I want to minimize it as much as possible to reduce uneeded spacing

Comment: what is your expected UI?

Comment: I want them to be on the same line without any spacing below each

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try wrapping the `Row widget` in a `SizedBox` widget with a smaller height.

```
SizedBox(
  height: 30, // adjust the height as needed
  child: Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      // ...
    ],
  ),
),
```

Answer (score 0):

ListTile comes with default height, For your case you can remove ListTile widget. Also Check padding on `IconButton`, you may just need `InkWell`

```dart
  double get _defaultTileHeight {
    final bool hasSubtitle = subtitle != null;
    final bool isTwoLine = !isThreeLine && hasSubtitle;
    final bool isOneLine = !isThreeLine && !hasSubtitle;

    final Offset baseDensity = visualDensity.baseSizeAdjustment;
    if (isOneLine) {
      return (isDense ? 48.0 : 56.0) + baseDensity.dy;
    }
    if (isTwoLine) {
      return (isDense ? 64.0 : 72.0) + baseDensity.dy;
    }
    return (isDense ? 76.0 : 88.0) + baseDensity.dy;
  }
```